# F# Flatten Function Efficiency Comparison

Tags: f#, complexity-theory, time-complexity, asymptotic-complexity

I'm trying to compare these two functions to see which has the best algorithm. I been looking at Order of n complexity, and although I don't know how to arrive at it mathematically (which is a shame) I can sometimes guess the order. I think to know if the algorithm is better than another I need to look at them in terms of asymptotic time, complexity and experimentally.

```
let flatten1 xs = List.fold (@) [] xs

let flatten2 xs = List.foldBack (@) xs []
```

I used the F# `#time` feature and this is what I got.

```
Real: 00:00:00.001, CPU: 00:00:00.000, GC gen0: 0, gen1: 0, gen2: 0
val it : int list =
  [1; 2; 3; 5; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6; 7; 8; 9; 10; 11; 12; 13; 14; 15; 16; 17; 18; 19;
   20; 5; 4; 5; 6]
>
Real: 00:00:00.001, CPU: 00:00:00.000, GC gen0: 0, gen1: 0, gen2: 0
val it : int list =
  [1; 2; 3; 5; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6; 7; 8; 9; 10; 11; 12; 13; 14; 15; 16; 17; 18; 19;
   20; 5; 4; 5; 6]
```

Comment: That current benchmark is going to be dominated by noise - you should show some actual code and test with that.  Also you need to consider the time complexity of your inner function (Hint: `@` is not constant time)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `xs` of length `n` and each operation `f` is O(1), `List.fold f xs` and `List.foldBack f xs` have the same complexity `O(n)`.

However, `@` is more complex than that. Assume that you run `flatten1` and `flatten2` on `xs` of length `n` where each of elements is a list of length `m`. The resulting list is of length `n*m`

Since `@` is `O(k)` where `k` is length of the first list, complexity of `flatten1` is:

```
// After each `@` call, the first list (the accumulator) increases its length by `m`
O(m + 2*m + 3*m + ... + (n-1)*m) 
= O(n*(n-1)*m/2)
```

In case of `flatten2`, the first list is always a list of length `m`:

```
O(m + m + ... + m) // n-1 steps
= O((n-1)*m)
```

You can easily see that `flatten2` will be much more efficient than `flatten1`. Difference in time complexity will dominate the extra allocation of `List.foldBack` anyway. To illustrate, here is a quick test showing the difference

```
let flatten1 xs = List.fold (@) [] xs
let flatten2 xs = List.foldBack (@) xs []

let xs = [ for _ in 1..1000 -> [1..100] ]

#time "on";;

// Real: 00:00:01.456, CPU: 00:00:01.466, GC gen0: 256, gen1: 124, gen2: 1
let xs1 = flatten1 xs;;

// Real: 00:00:00.007, CPU: 00:00:00.000, GC gen0: 1, gen1: 0, gen2: 0
let xs2 = flatten2 xs;;
```

Note that you can just use [List.concat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370370.aspx), an efficient implementation of `flatten` function.

Answer (score 1):

If in doubt go and look at the source (from /src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/list.fs)

```
    // this version doesn't causes stack overflow - it uses a private stack 
    [<CompiledName("FoldBack")>]
    let foldBack<'T,'State> f (list:'T list) (acc:'State) = 
        let f = OptimizedClosures.FSharpFunc<_,_,_>.Adapt(f)
        match list with 
        | [] -> acc
        | [h] -> f.Invoke(h,acc)
        | [h1;h2] -> f.Invoke(h1,f.Invoke(h2,acc))
        | [h1;h2;h3] -> f.Invoke(h1,f.Invoke(h2,f.Invoke(h3,acc)))
        | [h1;h2;h3;h4] -> f.Invoke(h1,f.Invoke(h2,f.Invoke(h3,f.Invoke(h4,acc))))
        | _ -> 
            // It is faster to allocate and iterate an array than to create all those 
            // highly nested stacks.  It also means we won't get stack overflows here. 
            let arr = toArray list
            let arrn = arr.Length
            foldArraySubRight f arr 0 (arrn - 1) acc
```

and fold

```
    [<CompiledName("Fold")>]
    let fold<'T,'State> f (s:'State) (list: 'T list) = 
        match list with 
        | [] -> s
        | _ -> 
            let f = OptimizedClosures.FSharpFunc<_,_,_>.Adapt(f)
            let rec loop s xs = 
                match xs with 
                | [] -> s
                | h::t -> loop (f.Invoke(s,h)) t
            loop s list
```

from this we can see that both have the same time complexity `(O(n))`.  As both perform a single loop over the data.  However, you could easily implement `foldback` in a way that was `O(n^2)`.  It appears from the code that there are more overheads in `foldback` as a temporary array is created to enable traversing the list in reverse order.

Comment: Your claim is not quite true in this case where the `List.foldBack` version is more efficient than the `List.fold` version.

Comment: @pad - yes you are right, I felt that the particular operation wasn't that important so I left it out